# How can I uninstall the last installed application (recently installed) with dpkg?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, deb, dpkg

I need to use a command and or script  that uninstalls the last recently installed application deb . I can't use apt-get in this case but rather dpkg --purge or similar, something like dpkg --remove (last recently installed application) but without providing the name of the application.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | head -n 1 | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -n1 basename | sed -e "s/.list//"
```

ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list : gives you the list of package sorted by date

head -n 1 : gives you the first item

awk '{print $8}' : gives you the fullpath filename

xargs -n1 basename : gives the filename , like curl.list

sed -e "s/.list//" | gives you the package name

Comment: this is useful  ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/* | head -n 1 |  sed -e "s/.list//"
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         1568 Oct 25 21:34 /var/lib/dpkg/info/ttf-droid

Comment: But I just want to return the end of the string,the name of the application ,get "ttf-droid" and save it in a variable for example

Comment: LAST_PACKAGE=`ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | head -n 1 | awk '{print $8}' | xargs -n1 basename | sed -e "s/.list//"`
echo $LAST_PACKAGE    

Now you have a variable.

Comment: `awk` can do `head` and `basename` can remove a suffix, but without the `-l` option to `ls` you don't need `awk`. The syntax in the last comment is wrong, probably because of the markup eating the backticks. Try `LAST_PACKAGE=$(ls -t /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | sed -e 's%.*/%%' -e 's%\.list$%%' -ep -eq); echo $LAST_PACKAGE`

Comment: in ruby, I found this solution package = %x[ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/* | head -n 1 | sed -e "s/.list//" | awk '{print $9}' | sed -e "s/...................//"] ,target = package.to_s.strip and finally, system ("dpkg --purge #{target}")

Answer (score 0):

Finding the last installed package is relatively simple. It's the newest entry in /var/lib/pkg/info.

However, uninstalling that will not necessarily restore the system to its prior state.

Installing a package will also install all of its dependencies. So, to really undo the install you also need to undo those dependencies. You can see that 'libfoo' was updated around the same time as 'appbar'. However, the info files will not tell if the previous state was no 'libfoo', or just an older version of 'libfoo'.

Comment: this is useful  ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/* | head -n 1 |  sed -e "s/.list//"
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         1568 Oct 25 21:34 /var/lib/dpkg/info/ttf-droid
But I just want to return the end of the string,the name of the application ,get "ttf-droid" and save it in a variable for example